# convert multi array into single array(java)

Tags: java, arrays

is it possible to copy the data from multi[][] to single[]?!?

```
double multi[][] = { {1.0, 2.0}, {2.11, 204.00, 11.00, 34.00},{66.5,43.3,189.6}};
```

to

```
double single [] = {1.0, 2.0, 2.11, 204.00, 11.0, 66.5,43.3,189.6}
```

Comment: What did you try? Poste some code how you would to it.

Comment: FYI: in Java its common to write `double[][] multi` instead of `double multi[][]`. Since you have an array of arrays of double (`double[][]`) and not an array of arrays of multi :)

Comment: @GameDroids - Actually, the two forms are identical in effect when only one variable is being declared. The difference comes when more than one variable is declared on a line: `double multi[][], single[];` declares `multi` to be a two-dimensional array and `single` to be a one-dimensional array; if the line starts with `double[][] ...` then everything is a two-dimensional array (or an array of two-dimensional arrays). You could, however, write: `double[] multi[], single;` to get the desired declarations. (I don't understand the part of your comment about "array of arrays of multi".)

Answer (score 4):

With Java 8 you can write:

```
double[] single = Arrays.stream(multi) //Creates a Stream<double[]>
            .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream) //merges the arrays into a DoubleStream
            .toArray(); //collects everything into a double[] array
```

Comment: Nice solution. Just out of curiosity (since I'm not using Java 8 yet), would this properly handle an element of `multi` being `null`?

Comment: @TedHopp No that would throw a NPE - but you could add a `.filter(Objects.nonNull)` before `flatMapToDouble` to skip null entries.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible. Per [@assylias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740196/535871), Java 8 has a very nice solution. If you're not using Java 8, you'll have to do some work by hand. Since the `multi` elements are different length, The most efficient thing to do would be to use two passes: the first to count how many elements you need in the result and the second to actually copy the elements once you've allocated the array:

```
int n = 0;
for (int[] elt : multi) {
    n += elt.length;
}
double[] single = new double[n];
n = 0;
for (int[] elt : multi) {
    System.arraycopy(elt, 0, single, n, elt.length);
    n += elt.length;
}
```

If it is at all possible that an element of `multi` is `null`, you'd want to add an appropriate check inside each of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a logical way..first you have to find the length of multy array content .and then make  single [] with that length and add values

```
double multy[][] = { {1.0, 2.0}, {2.11, 204.00, 11.00, 34.00},{66.5,43.3,189.6}};
int y=0;
for(int x=0;x<multy.length,x++){
    for(int i=0;i<multy[x].length,i++){
       y++;
    }
}
double single [] =new double[y];
y=0;

for(int x=0;x<multy.length,x++){
    for(int i=0;i<multy[x].length,i++){
       y++;
       single[y]==multy[x][i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686499/java-how-to-convert-a-multidimensional-array-to-single-array-easily

ArrayUtils.addAll(array1,array2)

Comment: This is an incorrect (or at least incomplete) solution. `ArrayUtils.addAll` will return a new array that is the concatenation of `array1` and `array2`. OP wants to concatenate all elements of `multi`. One can build on `addAll` to concatenate elements one at a time, but that is wildly inefficient. Furthermore, `ArrayUtils` is not part of the standard API; it require using the third-party Apache Commons library.